# SQL select default value only if specific value does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to join 2 tables based on multiple columns, but want to return the results from a default row if a specific value doesn't exist for any given column.

Below are samples of the 2 tables I'm trying to join:

### DATA_TABLE:

```
 ID      CATEGORY_1          CATEGORY_2         CATEGORY_3
 1           Y                   Y                  Y 
 2           Y                   N                  N 
 3           Y                   N                  Y
```

### ACCOUNT_TABLE:

```
 CATEGORY_1       CATEGORY_2     CATEGORY_3     ACCT_NUM
     Y                Y              Y            123
     Y                N              ALL          234
     ALL              ALL            Y            345
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to have ACCOUNT_TABLE.ACCT_NUM selected if data matches on CATEGORY_1, 2 and 3, but if it doesn't, then choose the ACCT_NUM associated with the "ALL" value from ACCOUNT_TABLE. Furthermore, if multiple records can be found because of the "ALL" value in ACCOUNT_TABLE, I want to return the ACCT_NUM based on priority (ie. matching on CATEGORY_1 would take precedence over a match on CATEGORY_2).

So far, the query I have written is as below:

```
 select d.*, a.acct_num from data_table d, account_table a
  where d.category_1 = DECODE(a.category_1,'ALL',d.category_1,a.category_1)
  and d.category_2 = DECODE(a.category_2,'ALL',d.category_2,a.category_2)
  and d.category_3 = DECODE(a.category_3,'ALL',d.category_3,a.category_3)
```

But my output looks like this:

```
 ID    CATEGORY_1       CATEGORY_2     CATEGORY_3     ACCT_NUM
 1         Y                Y              Y            123
 1         Y                Y              Y            345
 2         Y                N              N            234
 3         Y                N              Y            234
 3         Y                N              Y            345
```

For ID 1, I only want ACCT_NUM 123 to be returned, as matching on categories 1, 2, and 3 should take precedence over the "ALL" record.

ID 2 is matching correctly and returning the expected ACCT_NUM.

ID 3 I want to return ACCT_NUM 234, as matching on categories 1+2 should take precedence over matching on category 3.

So below would be my expected output:

```
 ID    CATEGORY_1       CATEGORY_2     CATEGORY_3     ACCT_NUM
 1         Y                Y              Y            123
 2         Y                N              N            234
 3         Y                N              Y            234
```

Any help/advice on how to write a query to achieve the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may best be done with a correlated subquery.  In Oracle 12g, you could do:

```
select d.*,
       (select a.acct_num
        from account_table a
        where (d.category_1 = a.category_1 or a.category_1 = 'ALL') and
              (d.category_2 = a.category_2 or a.category_2 = 'ALL') and
              (d.category_3 = a.category_3 or a.category_3 = 'ALL')
        order by ((case when a.category_1 = 'ALL' then 1 else 0 end) +
                  (case when a.category_2 = 'ALL' then 1 else 0 end) +
                  (case when a.category_3 = 'ALL' then 1 else 0 end)
                 ) asc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as acct_num       
from data_table d;
```

That is, fetch the match with the fewest "All" values.

In earlier versions of Oracle, you can do the same thing with aggregation and `keep`:

```
select d.*,
       (select max(a.acct_num) keep (dense_rank first
                                     order by ((case when a.category_1 = 'ALL' then 1 else 0 end) +
                                               (case when a.category_2 = 'ALL' then 1 else 0 end) +
                                               (case when a.category_3 = 'ALL' then 1 else 0 end)
                                              ) asc
                                     )
        from account_table a
        where (d.category_1 = a.category_1 or a.category_1 = 'ALL') and
              (d.category_2 = a.category_2 or a.category_2 = 'ALL') and
              (d.category_3 = a.category_3 or a.category_3 = 'ALL')

       ) as acct_num       
from data_table d;
```

You can also do something similar with a `join` and then using `row_number()` for the ranking.

Comment: hmm first suggestion won't work for me as I'm not on Oracle 12g, 2nd suggestion seems close, but output is a little bit off, IDs 2 and 3 are showing NULL acct_nums in the output.

Comment: @MattO . . . Do you have the "all" values as `ALL` or `All`?  Mixing up the case in Oracle can cause  a problem.

Comment: that was it! I don't know how I missed that. Thanks for your help Gordon!

Comment: @MattO . . . It was my fault.  I put the mixed case version in my answer.

Comment: Gordon - how do I get the priority to work? I will post another example in my next answer in this thread, as comments don't seem to allow formatting.